# How do I loop a full SoapUI project?

Tags: soapui

I have a SoapUI project that I would like to loop x number of times. How do I go about doing this? I can do this for a testcase by doing this -

```
if( context.loopIndex == null )
context.loopIndex = 0

if( ++context.loopIndex < 10 )
testRunner.gotoStepByName( "Step to start looping from" )

log.info(context.loopIndex)
```

Is there a way to get it to start from the beginning of the project?

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: i have a full script, i just want it to to do the same thing 10 times. I am guessing this isnt allowed as loadui exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the java code snippet that will run a soapui project number of times given for count.

```java
com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
runner.setProjectFile( "project/path/sample-soapui-project.xml" );
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
  runner.run(); 
}
```

You may look at for more details
http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html